# IIS 7 Express on VS 2010 Win 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I'm writing some http handlers using vs 2010 on a win 7 virtual machine.  I have not been able to discover how to configure the mappings for particular extensions and verbs using IIS 7 Express.  For example

extension = Foo
Executable = ../aspnet_isapi.dll
Verbs = get, head, post

Does anyone know where I might find that info?

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ: [IIS Express FAQ](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/)

> Q: Does IIS Express use the same configuration system as IIS 7.x?
>
> A: Yes, IIS Express uses the same applicationhost.config and
>   web.config files supported by IIS 7.x. The key difference is that with
>   IIS Express, the configuration is maintained on a per-user basis. In
>   particular, whereas IIS has a global “applicationhost.config” file,
>   IIS Express maintains a user-specific “applicationhost.config” file in
>   the %userprofile%\documents\IISexpress\config” folder. This lets a
>   standard user run IIS Express and also lets multiple users work on the
>   same machine independently, without conflicting with each other. Some
>   settings require Administrator user rights to set and modify (see
>   question above about running as a standard user).

Comment: Thank you.  Reading the FAQ and looking at applicationhost.config suggests that any changes that are made are made globally (to that user) while I hoped to modify them on a per application basis.

Comment: if you need a real IIS, I would really use IIS and not Express edition.

Comment: I was just hoping IIS Express would be easier.  For most things it probably is, for this, probably not.